# Hair not showing on certain objects

Tags: particles, hair

everyone. I made a building using multiple objects and now I'm trying to apply hair to certain objects to make it look like grass growing on an old ruin, however, it doesn't work on all of the objects. I'm trying to apply it to the roof (the object selected in the image attached), but nothing happens when I try. If I make a new object, like the square in the image, it does it without any issue. So far I can only make hair to appear in the dome and the basement. ¿Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: can be a lot of reasons. can you provide your blend file?

Comment: Just added the blend file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your bevel modifier, then it works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know I had to apply the modifier in order for the hair to work. Great!

Comment: You are welcome